# Spring : Join entity with one row table without join column

Tags: java, spring

I want to join table A with  table B in Spring Boot.

Table A has multiple rows but table B has only one row (with general parameters, by the way)

**There is no joining columns between these two tables**

I just want to use a column from table B in entity class of table A

Table A

```
@Getter
@Setter 
@Entity
@Table(name="tableA")
public class tableA {
 
     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "code")
     private String code; 

 }
```

TableB has only one row with one column "codeformatt"

```
    | codeformat |
    |------------|
    | AAAAA-AAAA |
```

this is the format for the code of tableA. I want to use it yo display code with the proper format.

**There are no foreign keys or joining columns**

If I had to write it in SQL I would write it like this:

```
   select A.code , B.codeformat
   from tableA A inner join tableB B on (1=1)
```

Does anyone has any clue how to do it?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Comment: Can you add code snippets with your data structure and what you have achieved so far. By the way, *Spring Boot* is a general purpose framework and has nothing to have with data by its own. So please describe you used stack (*Spring Data*, *Spring JPA*...)

Comment: For me, the question is unclear. Could you [edit] the post and give an example of what result is expected, given data in table `A` and `B`?

Comment: what about setting up a foreign key between the two tables ?? Just asking...

Comment: Can you try this  in your A entity as getter of class B:  `@Formula("select * from B")
    public B getB() {
        return B;
    }`

Comment: No foreign keys to setting up

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go with a custom query using @Query annotation.

```
@Query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM A tb1, B tb2 WHERE ...")
```

Like this.